Dependent pair recursion under lambda
I'm trying to write code where I transform a curried representation of a function to a function taking a Vect argument. With the function structures I've tried, I got stuck, because I'd need to know the Vect length or the head of the Vect before the point where I got it available. Which recursion structure can I use to make freeToVectReader compile? With my current code I get

Mismatch between: _ (implicitly bound at Program:35:7--35:48) and len (implicitly bound at Program:35:7--35:48).

module Main

import Data.Vect

data Free : (f : Type -> Type) -> (a : Type) -> Type where
  Pure : a -> Free f a
  Bind : f (Free f a) -> Free f a

data Reader r a = MkReader (r -> a)

runReader : Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader (MkReader f) = f

Functor (Reader r) where
    map f (MkReader g) = MkReader (f . g)

Applicative (Reader r) where
    pure x = MkReader (\_ => x)
    MkReader f <*> MkReader g = MkReader (\r => (f r) (g r))

Monad (Reader r) where
    MkReader f >>= g = MkReader (\r => runReader (g (f r)) r)

ask : Reader r r
ask = MkReader id

local : (r -> r) -> Reader r a -> Reader r a
local f (MkReader g) = MkReader (g . f)

freeToVectReader : Free (Reader ()) a -> (m : Nat ** Reader (Vect m ()) a)
freeToVectReader (Pure x) = (0 ** MkReader (\_ => x))
freeToVectReader (Bind f) = (_ ** do
  r :: rs <- ask
  let nextFree = runReader f r
  let (_ ** reader) = freeToVectReader nextFree
  local (const rs) reader)

I did manage to write the following simplified function. Maybe that helps?
-- Nat is the number of arguments
IntFun : Nat -> Type
IntFun 0 = Int
IntFun (S n) = Int -> IntFun n

funToVectReader : {n : Nat} -> IntFun n -> Reader (Vect n Int) Int
funToVectReader f = case n of
   0 => MkReader (\[] => f)
   S k => MkReader $ \(x :: xs) : Vect (S k) Int => runReader (funToVectReader (f x)) xs


I'm not convinced this function exists, since the result of runReader f r, including its effects, depends on the value of r.

You're right, thanks! I've updated my question to only allow a single value () for r, but I still can't figure out how to do the dependent pair recursion, as the witness for the length is scoped to the continuation of the monad bind, though I need it in the outer scope.
